# Use Xbox games or SkyDrive without switching to Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-account

I have Microsoft Account (outlook.com account). I use Windows 8.1 Client.

Can I use Xbox games or SkyDrive on my OS without switching my local user account to Microsoft Account? In Windows 8 it was possible - I was logged as local user to Windows, and gave my account only to application. Now, when I want to log in to MS Account, OS always forces me to connect my local user account with my MS Account.

So, how do I put this in easiest way possible...
I want to be able to use a local account on Windows 8.1 Client Operating System. I want to be able to use SkyDrive app, that will use my MS Account for cloud storage. I want to be able to play games from Windows Store, but I don't want to use my MS Account (my user profile and password) to log in to Windows PC.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Xbox 360 games cannot be played on Windows.  The Xbox Windows Service I think your talking about has actually been discontinued by Microsoft.  Clarify of your question if this comment makes no sense

Comment: Maybe I used wrong name. Games app, it requires xbox.com account.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about now.  When you link a `Microsoft Account to a `Windows User Profile` a new user profile is actually created.  Have you done this or are you just connecting the Windows Store to your Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to use Skydrive with Windows 8.1 in local account. Add Skydrive as [network drive](http://www.flgoo.com/enable-skydrive-windows-8-1-local-account/).